# How to get list of items from ListStore in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt, gwt-rpc

I am working on some GWT app and I need a list of items from my RpcProxy method :

```
RpcProxy<PagingLoadResult<GwtAccessRole>> proxy = new RpcProxy<PagingLoadResult<GwtAccessRole>>() {

            @Override
            protected void load(Object loadConfig, AsyncCallback<PagingLoadResult<GwtAccessRole>> callback) {
                GWT_ACCESS_ROLE_SERVICE.findByUserId((PagingLoadConfig) loadConfig, currentSession.getSelectedAccount().getId(), userId, callback);

            }
        };
```

The only thing that I done is that I made BasePagingLoader and then ListSore:

```
BasePagingLoader<PagingLoadResult<GwtAccessRole>> loader = new BasePagingLoader<PagingLoadResult<GwtAccessRole>>(proxy);
        ListStore<GwtAccessRole> accessRoleStore = new ListStore<GwtAccessRole>(loader);

        for (GwtAccessRole gwtAccessRoleChecked : accessRoleStore.getModels()) {
            for (GwtRole gwtRole : roleStore.getModels()) {
                if (gwtAccessRoleChecked.getId().equals(gwtRole.getId())) {
                    listCheckedRoles.add(gwtRole);
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried to iterate through ListStore through accessRoleStore.getModels but it says its empty, but I know that list is not empty. Does anyone have idea how to make a list of items from this mine ListStore?

Comment: Is there any filtering going on? The various store methods return only the _visible_ items, so if the store is not empty but getModels() returns an empty list, this means that all items were removed by filters. If not, how are you sure the list isn't empty? Any chance you are running into a timing issue around that async call?

Comment: Yep, I'm going to double down on the async idea - in your code sample you are looping through `getModels()` right after you create the store, so the items haven't even been added to the store yet. Instead, wait for the Load event to go off on the loader, indicating that results have successfully come back from the server.